# What is the best automated web testing tool for GWT?

Tags: gwt, automated-tests

I'm interested to do automatic testing on GWT applications.
I know not all automated web testing tools can cope with dynamic AJAX web frameworks such as GWT.
Anyone with positive experience here?

Comment: Selenium / WebDriver ? (never used them myself, so I can't give "positive experience" feedback; but Google is using them AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [GwtUnitTest](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-cq07247/index.html) ?

I know this isn't black box testing, but it allows test ajax.

Also I have practive with implementing ajax tests with [TestComplete](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/). But development of those test cases is complicated.